# How to ink to another .html page within Chrome extension/app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome app for a client that will run in kiosk mode to display in their stores. Right now I have an index.html page that links to about 30 other pages. However, when I click on a link in the app I get an error...

`Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://leghflngpfmomcflabikghiemaajadne/poweredge"; try target="_blank".`

So I tried target="_blank" and that tries to open it in a new chrome window.. no good. I've been reading a little bit about using webview and sandboxing pages but they both open the pages in a new window and it just doesn't look good.

Is there a better way to do this? Right now my only idea is to place all of the content on the index.html page and turn on/off sections of the content with jQuery. I'd love to keep all of the pages separate though, just for my own sanity.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently linking to the page?  What's the html code?

Comment: Chrome Apps no wayfor  window navigation, so you can implement WebView and open your index.html once in WebView.

Comment: This is a good example of kiosk: https://github.com/zebradog/kiosk

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm just using regular html links.. `<a href="..`

Answer (score 1):

[Navigation is disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) for the Chrome Apps platform. In theory you are supposed to make single-page apps - so your turn on/off approach is the "intended" one.

No-one stops you from having several windows though - suppose you have an options page, it wouldn't be strange to open it separately (via `chrome.app.window.create`)

As stdob mentions in comments, a workaround may be possible by using `<webview>` with a partition [blessed to show local resources](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#local_resources). It's not clear though if it will allow access to apps APIs.

Comment: Using webview to load local resources is not a good idea. Webview is useful for loading live content from the web. Load local resources using xhr and modify DOM (just manage your content).