# How to open page in chrome app via html link

Tags: html, google-chrome-app

I am trying to convert my html webpage to chrome app, and have found this error:

When trying to click a link to another page within my app, it does not work. I click it and nothing happens. I had a look around, and read that I need to include **target="_blank"**, but that just comes up with an error saying that there is no application set to open that file. I would like the page to open *within* the chrome app wrapper.

Here is my code: `<a href="Cookie game.html">Click here to play</a>`

Comment: is it app or extension?

Comment: It shows up in both app and extension lists

Comment: did you try  Cookie-game.html   ( without space )?  or what is the error that you got

Comment: @Max, unfortunately navigation is included in the list of disabled web feature but have provide [workaround](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) for the disabled features. Some related question provided sample workarounds [link html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481841/how-to-ink-to-another-html-page-within-chrome-extension-app?rq=1) and [open new window in a web view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428668/how-to-open-a-new-window-from-a-link-in-a-webview-in-a-chrome-packaged-app?rq=1). I hope these examples help you

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Rebot this might be usefull, however it would have to be slightly different than how I originally planned it.